# php illuminate/container one interface how to bind two different instance in one class

Tags: containers, ioc-container

In packagist illuminate/container 
I want to use the Observer.

But one interface how to bind two different instance in one class ?

Can I use the Closure ? How do I use it ?

```
class User extends Controller {
    public function save(Subject $user, Observer $department, Observer $permission) 
    {
        $user->attach($department);
        $user->attach($permission);
        $user->doSomething();
    } 
} 

interface Observer { 
    function bind($object, Subject $subject); 
}

class DepartmentService implements Observer
{
    function bind($object, Subject $subject)
    {
    }
}

class PermissionService implements Observer
{
    function bind($object, Subject $subject)
    {
    }
}

interface Subject
{
    function attach(Observer $observer);
    function detach(Observer $observer);
    function notify($user);
}
```

Think you for your answer !

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please update your  code in the question.

Comment: In the Controller two Observer how do I use the container to bind?